# Can we change from kafta based ordering service to raft based ordering in production and vice versa in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

As hyperledger fabric has introduced new ordering service called RAFT, I would like to understand whether we can change from Kaft-based ordering service to RAFT based ordering service in production and vice versa.

It would be very helpful if there is document to explain implication of changing ordering service in future.

Thank you.

Comment: I responded below, but probably better to use chat.hyperledger.org

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently do this.  We are currently implementing the ability to migrate from Kafka to Raft and expect to ship this capability in the 1.4.2 release.

Comment: Thank you Gari Singh, Looking forward for Fabric1.4.2 release :)